# Error 404 in weblogic

Tags: deployment, weblogic, weblogic12c

Does anyone know what is this error in web logic 12.2.1.2

> Caused By: com.bea.common.store.service.StoreInitializationException:
>   [Security:099060]The URL specified for the data store connection is
>   invalid: ldap://null:-1,please check all host configuration
>   parameters.

Why does this happen and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `URL` seems to be **wrong**. The URL could be wrong with some unexpected white spaces.
Double check your `URL` and remove any white spaces.

Check out [this](https://techworldrocks.wordpress.com/2011/09/16/weblogic-server-as-windows-service/) link.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused By: com.bea.common.store.service.StoreInitializationException:
>   [Security:099060]The URL specified for the data store connection is
>   invalid: ldap://null:-1,please check all host configuration
>   parameters.

A common cause of the above trace is when the **Admin server is not reachable**. Check if you are externally able to connect to admin server. If you are using a startup script also check for below parameter :

```
-Dweblogic.management.server
```